# Print the type of a parameter (ParmVarDecl) with clang API

Tags: c++, llvm, clang

I need to print the type of a parameter in a C++ source file using the clang API.

If I have a parameter representation in clang (`ParmVarDecl* param`) I can print the name of the parameter using `param->getNameAsString()`. I would need a method **`param->getTypeAsString()`**, but there is no such method. So is there another way to do this task?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Got the answer to my question in the llvm irc:

There is a method `std::string clang::QualType::getAsString(SplitQualType split)`

So this does work for me:

```
ParmVarDecl* param = *someParameter;
cout << QualType::getAsString(param->getType().split()) << endl;
```

Comment: You probably just saved me a week

Comment: You certainly saved me the entire night.

Comment: You need to add a clang::PrintingPolicy nowadays. Such that the call now looks like: `QualType::getAsString(param->getType().split(), PrintingPolicy{ {} })`

Answer (score -6):

You can use `typeid` to get the name of any type.  Although it will vary from compiler to compiler, and may not be a pretty name.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

struct MyStruct { };

int main()
{
    std::cout << typeid(MyStruct).name() << std::endl;
}
```

If you need to do this for a lot of classes, you could make the call part of a base class, then any class that needs the functionality can just inherit from it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

class NamedClass
{
  public:
    virtual ~NamedClass() { }

    std::string getNameAsString()
    {
        return typeid(*this).name();
    }
};

class MyStruct : public NamedClass
{
};

int main()
{
    MyStruct ms;
    std::cout << ms.getNameAsString() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: How this is connected to the question asked? The q. was about clang API, he wanted to do this on the clang AST.

Comment: Like Anton wrote, I want to do this with the clang API, so that when I process a source file, I can print functions and their parameter types. But I'll try your answer, maybe I can get use of it.