# Print a fully qualified type of a parameter (ParmVarDecl) or a field (FieldDecl) with clang Libtooling API

Tags: c++, clang, libtooling

Similar to this question: [Print the type of a parameter (ParmVarDecl) with clang API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671757/print-the-type-of-a-parameter-parmvardecl-with-clang-api), I want to get parameter/field type as a string, but importantly I want the type to be fully qualified, e.g. for

```
namespace n {
class A {};
class B {
    void f(std::vector<A> a) {}
    std::vector<A> m_a;
};
} // n
```

I want to have `std::vector<n::A>`, not `std::vector<A>`.

I've tried this solution: http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/Getting-the-fully-scoped-type-of-a-function-parameter-td4028221.html (getAsCXXRecordDecl() and getQualifiedNameAsString()), but in both cases `decl.getType()->getAsCXXRecordDecl()` returns `nullptr` for me.

Update: Also, this solution [How to print fully qualified Expr in clang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57433002/how-to-print-fully-qualified-expr-in-clang?rq=1) doesn't help, because there is no PrintCanonicalTypes in clang 7 I'm using.

I guess I'll have to upgrade to clang 8 and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PrintCanonicalTypes` flag does help with printing fully-qualified method/function parameters (in combination with `decl.getOriginalType().getCanonicalType().getAsString(...)`).

For fields I've used `decltype()` of a field name instead of an explicit type, which worked for me (because I didn't need types per se, rather the generated code to compile).